# Updating Lambda Alias to new version does not work immediately

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

After new code is pushed to lambda, I am running the following comands

Create new version from the $LATEST code

```
ver=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name my-function --description "New version" --output text --query 'Version')
```

Point lambda alias to new version

```
aws lambda update-alias --function-name my-function --name dev --function-version $ver
```

Then if I check the Alias in AWS console, it still shows it is pointing to old version.
The screen shot below shows Alias is still pointing to old version.

[image]

If I wait for few mins and refresh the console then I see alias is pointing to new version.
[image]

Does it take time for Alias to point to new version? or is it just a console that is not getting updated configuration immediately.

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue, (updating the default version and removing the additional weights after some period), can you send your current aws version

Comment: @DilLip_Chowdary Do you have provisioned concurrency enabled?

Answer (score 1):

This seem to be common issues.

Just curious, do you have provisioned concurrency & autoscaling turned on?

You can try change the `description` to something different on every `publish-version` (but I doubt the change would be immediate with provisioned concurrency turned on)

Comment: Yes, I do have provisioned concurrency

Comment: @LP13 Yeah, that could be the problem, you can try turn it off to test. It's faced by CDK users as well - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5334

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have canary deployment enabled. The canary configuration is creating the delay you're seeing. If you want to propagate your changes instantly, I'd recommend disabling the canary deployment.

[Canary Deployments with Alias Traffic Shifting](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-canary-deployments-of-aws-lambda-functions-with-alias-traffic-shifting/)

Comment: But how do you disable canary deployment? To update alias I am using the command `aws lambda update-alias --function-name my-function --name dev --function-version $ver` However this produce issue which I mentioned above.  So now I changed to `aws lambda update-alias --function-name my-function --name dev --function-version $ver --routing-config AdditionalVersionWeights={}` to assign 100% weight to new version. But still the same Issue.

Comment: Note that even if I use AWS Console to change the Alias to different version, it does not reflect the changes immediately.

Comment: My experience with Aliases is they update immediately. Can you post your stack?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

**API Version**

```
aws-cli/1.25.83 Python/3.8.10 Linux/5.8.0-63-generic botocore/1.29.125
```

**Steps:**

- Publish new version (returns latest version if no code changes)

```
ver=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name my-function --description "New version" --output text --query 'Version' )
```

- Update Alias with new version, additionally here we're clearing weighted config using `--routing -config AdditionalVersionWeights={}` (if any)

```
aws lambda update-alias --function-name my-function --name dev --function-version $ver --routing-config AdditionalVersionWeights={}
```

When I Check the Alias Config through cli as well as Console, I got the expected output immediately

```
aws lambda get-alias --function-name my-function --name dev
```

**Before:**
[image: Lambda Alias Details Before]

**After:**
[image: Lambda Alias Details After]

Comment: @Dilip_Chowdary. The issue here pointing Alias from version 3 to version 4 takes time. If you apply publish version and update alias immediately, and then check the console

Comment: Yeah I did the same,

Comment: but from your 1st screenshot it doesn't seems to apply changes immediately. Alias is still pointing to version 3

Comment: 1st screenshot is the before applying the Steps (publishing version), i just tried to reproduce the behaviour same as yours

Comment: Do you have provisioned concurrency enabled?

Comment: @LP13 No, provisioned concurrency is not enabled